# An issue with outputting log4j date in terminal (ubuntu)

Tags: java, eclipse, console, terminal, log4j

Hey I have problem with output the date format from log4j property in terminal.

Here's part from the prop. file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.err
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n
```

and the output in Eclipse is: `2013-06-10 14:38:21,478 INFO` but in terminal, where I expect the same output it's `13/06/10 14:38:21 INFO`

So any ideas how can i have the same output as the one in Eclipse, is it from the log4j property file or?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: When you mean "in terminal", do you mean running at the command line? Are you sure your log4j.properties file is in the classpath?

Comment: The server it's working with Linux Ubuntu.The property file is in the classpath but the output in the Linux terminal is different.

Comment: Are you _absolutely sure_ it is in the classpath? If you debug log4j, do you actually see that the file is used, the correct appenders are setup etc?

Comment: Yes I'm absolutely sure that it's in the classpath..the correct file is used.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this way.

```
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.DatePattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

set separately `DatePattern` and `conversionPattern` i thing it ll helps you.

Comment: It's the same as i can see..I mean it the output in the Terminal isn't changed and the one in Eclipse is the same also.The problem is about the difference between them two.I need them to be the same and scope is the one from Eclipse console output.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.Wrong place to change the output.The right properties was in hadoop dir. where log4j got prop file too and i didn't knew about it.So i changed the date format there and everything is OK now.Thanks anyway for the support.